# Dynamic Load CSS in Rails for IE

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have an app in `rails`. In my application, there are places where partial use.

Each partial to use, brings its own `CSS`

The problem shows up with our dear `Internet Explorer 7` and `Internet Explorer 8` which do not let me insert `CSS` outside header. I tried to do it the following way:

```
css=stylesheet_link_tag 'my_partial'
$(CSS).appendTo("head");
```

It is working perfectly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. However, I can not load the `CSS` in Internet Explorer. Can someone give me an idea of ​​how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should give more context.

Comment: i'm apply 'code'  <div class="wrapper replace">
            <div class="white_block">
              <div class="scotch_single scotch_center"></div>
              <%= render(partial: 'layouts/user_currents') %>
            </div>
        </div>
in the partial is:
=stylesheet_link_tag 'user_currents'
#currents
 .content_scroll
  .title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to include a `yield` section in the head section of your layout. You can then do `content_for` in each partial that includes your customised CSS.

eg in `layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- blah blah title and regular css here -->
  <%= yield :extra_stylesheets %>
</head>
...
```

Then in partials:

```
<% content_for :extra_stylesheets do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'my_partial_stylesheet' %>
<% end %>
```